# DocumentDB: Delete a document by ID

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using a new database from Microsoft called DocumentDB. Now I want to delete a document by ID, but I cannot figure out, how to do this. Delete operation in DocumentDB requires self-links and they are different from my own ids.

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(EndPoint, AuthKey))
{
    await client.DeleteDocumentAsync("**self-link here**");
}
```

I can execute an additional query to find the self-link and then pass it, but this will require two operations instead one and that is what I'd like to avoid. Is there a better way to remove an entry by ID without using queries or stored procedures?

Comment: +1 Exactly the same question that came to my mind; why does any operation, using the LINQ providers, require a *self-link* to a collection. The latter on its turn requires a *self-link* to the database.

Comment: Any possibility of sharing what that second operation looks like? Are you doing a simple "SELECT * FROM DOC WHERE ID=1"?

Answer (score 5):

*** UPDATE *** This feature has now been implemented

*** ORIGINAL ANSWER ***

Not today, no. You can head to http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb and vote for the feature there.

Comment: And [the vote is open](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333050-it-should-be-possible-to-remove-a-document-by-id) and rising.

Comment: Here is the code sample: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/

Comment: Note, this feature has now been implemented.

Comment: This answer doesn't currently answer the question with how to do it as far as I can tell. I think it should be edited

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I am deleting document

```
{                
var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_documentDataBaseId, _documentCollectionId, docId);
                await _documentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This features has now been implement (as of the 8/2015* - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333050-it-should-be-possible-to-remove-a-document-by-id

Comment: There is no code snippet showing the new feature there. It's here if anyone's looking: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/

Answer (score 0):

as there's no solution for this case I'd recommend to retrieve all the documents in the existing collection to get access to the SelfLink and _rid values.
I just started a mini wrapper to get access to DocumentDB in Universal Apps and hopefully CrossPlatform using Xamarin: https://github.com/JorgeCupi/documentDB-Win10UAP-wrapper feel free to give me any feedback, participate or request some needed methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code in nodejs to deletebyId and it works for me.

```
deleteDocumentById: function(params, callback) {
    var self = this,
        query= params.query,
        collection = params.collection;

    client.queryDocuments(collection._self, query, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        client.deleteDocument(docs[0]._self, docs[0], function(err, success) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, success);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was continuously receiving this error: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException:

> Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.,

The main trick of deleting is PartionKey id. You suppose inside PartionKey provide id
like in the code example. 
I have tried many ways, but I was always receiving different errors...Only this solution worked for me.

```
await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(input[0].SelfLink, 
  new RequestOptions
  {
     PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(input[0].Id)
  });
Hope this helps :)
```